# Install LE in a domain with no server?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, cpanel

My domain points to another website and I want to install LE cert for it, is that possible or my domain should be linked to the server?

Answer (score 0):

letsencrypt not allow to install non NS pointing because its check for reverse verification so it will be failed